# Customising Bootstrap path with grunt-sass

Tags: gruntjs, bower, bootstrap-sass

I've installed bootstrap-sass and grunt-sass, and want to customise the bootstrap components included in my build.

I've created a copy of `_bootstrap.scss` in my `app/styles/` folder and need to override the default import paths - what changes do I need to make to my Gruntfile for this to work?

I've tried including the full path the Bootstrap partials in my _bootstrap.scss file, but that doesn't compile. Gruntfile extract below.

**Gruntfile**

```
// Compiles Sass to CSS and generates necessary files if requested
sass: {
    options: {
        sourceMap: true,
        sourceMapEmbed: true,
        sourceMapContents: true,
        includePaths: ['.']
    },
    dist: {
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: '<%= config.app %>/styles',
          src: ['*.{scss,sass}'],
          dest: '.tmp/styles',
          ext: '.css'
        }]
      },
      server: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= config.app %>/styles',
          src: ['*.{scss,sass}'],
          dest: '.tmp/styles',
          ext: '.css'
        }]
      }
    },
```

Comment: It's not very clear what you are trying to accomplish. Can you break it down to smaller pieces?

Comment: I've installed bootstrap-sass but only want to include particular components. I don't want to modify the package source, I want to use my own version of _bootstrap.scss within my project - can I set the load path?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did using [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) and [Bower](http://bower.io/) along with Bootstrap to make a custom install including / excluding bootstrap components which might help you.

Once I had Grunt and Bower set up I added [bootstrap-sass](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass#c-bower) using `bower install boostrap-sass --save-dev` so that my bower.json file was updated.

**Modifying Bootstrap**

I imported `bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss` into my my `styles.scss` file.

Then edited `_bootstrap.scss` commenting out which ever components I didn't want or need.

Next, created a file called `_main.scss` and stored this in a subdirectory (partials) of where my `styles.scss` file was, then imported `_main.scss` below the `_bootstrap.scss`.

This way I could override bootstrap if need be with my own custom styles by editing `_main.scss`.

Here's a [starter grunt setup](https://github.com/chrisj-skinner/grunt-starter-setup) I used which might help explain the file structure.

**Styles.scss file**

```
// Bootstrap
@import 'bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap';

// Custom styles
@import 'partials/main';
```

**Gruntfile.js**

```
module.exports = function(grunt){

    // Configure task(s)
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        // setup uglify task
        uglify: {
            build: {
                files: {
                    'js/scripts.min.js': ['bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js', 'bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.min.js', 'src/js/*.js']
                },
            },
            dev: {
                options: {
                    beautify: true,
                    mangle: false,
                    compress: false,
                    preserveComments: 'all'
                },
                files: {
                    'js/scripts.min.js': ['bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js', 'bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js', 'src/js/*.js']
                },
            },
        },

        // setup watch task
        watch: {
            js: {
                files: ['bower_components/**/*.js', 'src/js/*.js'],
                tasks: ['uglify:dev']
            },
            css: {
                files: ['src/scss/**/*.scss'],
                tasks: ['sass:dev']
            },
        },

        // setup sass
        sass: {
            dev: {
                options: {
                     outputStyle: 'expanded'
                },
                files: {
                    'css/styles.min.css' : 'src/scss/styles.scss'
                },
            },
            build: {
                options: {
                    outputStyle: 'compressed'
                },
                files: {
                    'css/styles.min.css' : 'src/scss/styles.scss'
                },
            },
        },
    });

    // Load the plugins
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sass');

    // Register task(s)
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['uglify:dev','sass:dev']);
    grunt.registerTask('build', ['uglify:build', 'sass:build']);
};
```

From there you should be able to add your own custom bootstrap styles and / or remove components from bootstrap you don't want. Then just run `grunt` or `grunt build` depending on whether you want a development output (non minified or not). Or `grunt watch` while you are editing for instant compile. Add in [livereload](http://livereload.com/) chrome extension and the app and you'll have live updates across all files.

A couple of months late.. but hope this helps!